# Handlebars @../first - @first

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

Im trying to get the first item of a loop from within a second loop.

I know i get the @key like this @../key but @first doesn't seem to work the same way @../first

Any ideas?

regards

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: Are you sure `@../key` works?

Comment: Yes , @../key does work. Sure i could post the code but it wouldnt help, its not that my loop is wrong or something, i cant access the value.

Answer (score 3):

First, whether in a nested block or not, you *do not* get the value of the first item of a loop using `@first`. The [Handlebars documentation](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/data-variables.html#first) is quite clear that `@first` is a boolean value that is

> Set to true by the each helper for the first step of iteration.

If you are trying to obtain this boolean value from within an inner loop, I have created a demo that shows you *can* get this value in the parent scope with `@../first`. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/8L7a9tpL/

However, I suspect this does not solve your issue, and that your goal is to obtain a *value* from the outer loop. It's hard to know what you are trying to achieve since you haven't posted your code, but the solution *might* be found in the [Handlebars lookup builtin helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup). See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/qvb9b6mq/